# Use multiple mysql connections in one query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to select a union of two tables from different DBs and this DBs are secured with different users and password. Currently I am running two select queries and merging them up but I wish to find a way to connect to the two DBs at once and run a single select query on the two tables. Maybe something like `\DB::connection('mysql_1')->connection('mysql_2')` Any possible way to do this please

Comment: You're asking a couple of different things here; I'm not sure which (if *ANY*) of them are actually possible.  But look at this article: [Querying multiple MySQL databases at once](https://medium.com/swlh/querying-multiple-mysql-databases-at-once-7e92ae99f842)

Comment: A great solution, for optimization would be to split the 2 files that connect and draw data to the databases and then call both file's data into a single one(probably the one you will use to modify or display data from).

Answer (score 3):

A given MySQL connection only knows one MySQL instance. You can't connect to two instances at once on a single connection. The simplest solution is for you to continue doing what you are currently doing: query both, and union the results in your client application.

There are proxy solutions like Vitess or ProxySQL, but they are just handling the multiple connections for you. You're not really using two MySQL instances on the same connection, you're just delegating that work to the proxy.

There's a MySQL feature called the [FEDERATED storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html), which comes close to what you want. Basically, you can still only connect to one MySQL instance, but that MySQL instance can serve as a proxy to another MySQL instance on a table-by-table basis. That is, the federated table is not really stored on the primary MySQL instance to which you are connected. But you can query it like a view, and those queries are passed to the second MySQL instance. Results are passed through the federated engine and then to your calling application as if the table had existed on the primary MySQL instance. The FEDERATED engine is not enabled by default on modern versions of MySQL.